# Redirection with query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

On my website, I want to do the 301 following redirections :

1) /glossaire?cpage=n to /glossaire/page/n
where n is an integer > 1

2) /glossaire?cpage=1 to /glossaire

After many failed attemps, could you please tell me how to ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cpage=1$
RewriteRule ^glossaire/?$ /glossaire [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cpage=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^glossaire/?$ /glossaire/page/%1? [L,NC,R=301]
```